# Make Predicate return a bool value from async method C#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, predicate

How can I make the Predicate return a bool value from async method C#

```
private void OnFilterTextBoxTextChangedHandler(object oSender, TextChangedEventArgs oArgs)
{
 //Other operations
 _oCollectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(DoFilter); //wrong return type
}
```

Returning method

```
private async Task<bool> DoFilter(object oObject)
{
    if (_sFilterText == "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your `DoFilter` is not `async` method. It lacks `await`.

Comment: Even with await in the DoFilter method, the DoFilter method is not being awaited iteslf, so the return type is still a Task<bool> right?

Comment: @DovydasSopa Even if I make it await it doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: @MaxHampton Yes its still Task<bool>

Comment: @user6384353 I'm just saying that this code is not correct. Is this your full code? If so, why do you need `oObject` as parameter? If no, maybe you want to share your full code?

Comment: @DovydasSopa Yes, its not my full code, my thoughts were that would be irrelevant to my question. I do use the oObject parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[`Predicate<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) is a delegate. You don't need to instantiate a new predicate when adding a filter to your CollectionView. Instead, you can add your filter like this:

```
_oCollectionView.Filter = DoFilter;
```

Second, the signature of the CollectionView.Filter delegate is `public delegate bool Predicate<object>(object obj)`. The parameter obj is the element of the CollectionView that is being evaluated. You cannot alter this signature to make it asynchronous.

In your example, I would look at doing the following:

```
constructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Alternatively put this in an initialization method.
    _oCollectionView.Filter = DoFilter;
}

private async void OnFilterTextBoxTextChangedHandler(object oSender, TextChangedEventArgs oArgs)
{
    // Other operations

    // Asynchronous processing
    await SetupFilterAsync();
    _oCollectionView.Refresh();
}

private async Task SetupFilterAsync()
{
    // Do whatever you need to do async.
}

private bool DoFilter(object obj)
{
    // Cast object to the type your CollectionView is holding
    var myObj = (MyType) obj;
    // Determine whether that element should be filtered
    return myObj.ShouldBeFiltered;
}
```

You can also define your filter as a lambda, which would look like this and eliminate the DoFilter method:

```
_oCollectionView.Filter = x => ((MyType)x).ShouldBeFiltered;
```